# Wrong window gets focus when switching workspace

Tags: unity, workspaces

I enjoy using VLC to play video while I do other work.

The VLC window is set to by 'Always on top' and 'Always on visible workspace'.

In former versions of Ubuntu this has worked great. When I changed to a different workspace then whatever application I was working in would get the focus.

But in 12.04 the VLC window will now always steal focus when I switch workspace.

Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: Can confirm this in 14.04 as well.

Comment: Please try disabling always on top.

Comment: Wouldn't disabling 'always on top' make it .. not on top? Anyway, the question is two years old, there might be a way to do it now, but I don't use Ubuntu that often anymore.

Comment: My suggestion was based on the thought that always on top and always in focus might be somewhat synonymous. Seemed a very easy thing to try. The question is indeed almost 2 years old, however, the question appears to be still valid as @hakermania confirms it exists in 14.04. I'm just trying to do my part for the community, others may benefit even if you are no longer interested.

Comment: Using a different window manager would probably make it possible to fix this behavior.  KWin can probably do it just with its GUI settings; if not, it's scriptable.  Other window managers can probably do it too, but would require editing conf files.

Comment: @ElderGeek ahh, ok, then that might work. Hope someone will see your comment and maybe get it to work. And I agree that it's always good to help the community :)

Comment: I hope so too....

Comment: If you're using Compiz, and have CCSM installed, there is a place in the Window section to set windows that never get the focus, etc, that might work.

Answer (score 7):

Disable "Click to Focus" On CCSM,

Go to; General -> General Options -> Focus & Raise Behaviour => Disable "Click to Focus"

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the rep to leave a comment, so I'll put an answer and hope a mod puts it into a comment instead.

Try the setting for window under mouse has focus. Then you will need to test to see if it is based on the location of your mouse pointer. If the mouse invariable sits over your VLC window, when you switch desktop you may find that this window will grab focus by default.