# Eclipse loses focus after switching workspace

Tags: unity, 13.04, eclipse, workspaces

This might be related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154095/wrong-window-gets-focus-when-switching-workspace).

I am Using Ubuntu 13.04 and Eclipse Juno Service Release 2.

I use Eclipse with some Eclipse's Views(panes) detached from the main window, because I have two monitors.

However, in that environment, the main window always lose its focus after switching Ubuntu's workspace.  This is really annoying because I have to change the focus every time before I start coding.

This is how to reproduce the problem:

1. Open Eclipse, detach a pane (Project Explorer might be fine) from the main window, and focus on the main window.
2. Switch Ubuntu's (not Eclipse's) workspace.
3. Switch again back to the workspace where Eclipse exists.
4. Now the detached pane gets the focus, not the main window.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Some remarks: (1) Same 'problem' with the GIMP program where Brushes and Tool Options are in separate windows. (2) The 'problem' is not really related to Ubuntu 13.04. For the moment I'm running Openbox as a windowmanager, and also there the 'problem' persists. (3) I guess the 'problem' is related to a lower level, I mean the X windowing system

Comment: I have to add that this issue is called 'focus stealing'. Different windowmanagers use different methods to tackle the problem. It all depends on how the running application identifies the new window to the window manager.

Comment: As you say, GIMP also has the same problem in my environment.  This seems to be because detached panes are treated as Dialog type in X.  If they were really dialogs, the behavior might be reasonable.  [Compiz's website told me how to inspect each window's attributes](http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching), which is quite useful to understand this phenomenon.

Comment: Some types of "focus stealing" problems can be solved using CompizConfig Settings Manager.  However, my case seems to be different from them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with two screens.. One (slightly weird) solution to avoid undocking any panes is to stretch the window across two screens and keep the windows docked.